# Argument of type X is not assignable to parameter of type Y Object literal may only specify known properties

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

Good day. I'm new to Type Script, using sequelize with VSCode. I've been having problem with this since i migrated to typescript

```
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as sql from 'mssql';
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const sequelize: any = new Sequelize('my_reputation_db', 'sa', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',

    dialect: 'mssql',

    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    },
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'
    }
});
```

This is the error I'm getting

> Argument of type '{ host: string; dialect: string; pool: { max: number; min: number; acquire: number; idle: number;...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options | undefined'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'options' does not exist in type 'Options | undefined'.

Comment: I don't know anything about sequelize.  Does your code work at runtime?  According to the [specifications](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/sequelize/index.d.ts#L5439) for the fourth parameter to the `Sequelize` constructor, there is no `options` property.  There *is* a `dialectOptions` property which seems like what you're trying to do (using `tediousjs` and mssql?).

Comment: yes it works at runtime..but after testing with postman I keep getting unhandled rejection error

Comment: Are you *positive* that, at runtime, the `options: {encrypt: true, instanceName: 'SQLEXPRESS'}` parameter is being used?  According to the specifications, there is no `options` parameter.  There is only `dialectOptions`.

Comment: And if there is an error at runtime and you need help with it, you should post actual error messages and any relevant code for someone to reproduce.   Please make sure you're read about how to provide a [mcve].